# Is it possible to make trellis layered plot with vega-lite or vega

Tags: svg, png, visualization, vega, vega-lite

I would like to know if vega-Lite or Vega support making trellis visualizations having an extra layer?

I'm able to make both visualizations type but not combine them. My issue is that I would like to be able to save all layered figures at once using export to png/svg button.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Vega-Lite 2 supports view composition. Check out https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/composition.html and let us know if things are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else found this question but not the related others, refer to Jake's answer: [Can you have facets & layers in single Vegalite plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418895/can-you-have-facets-layers-in-single-vegalite-plot/64422039#64422039)

The short answer is that you need to use the Facet Operator (as opposed to the encoding). Refer to: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html#facet-operator

This means you set up your Vegalite spec like:

```
{
  "facet": {
    ... // Facet definition
  },
  "spec": { "layer": [...]}
}
```

You cannot user the Layer spec and put the facet encoding in that spec. I found this page conceptually helpful: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/spec.html#common - essentially use the Facet View Specification, as opposed to the Layer View Specification.