# Can you have facets & layers in single Vegalite plot?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am struggling to understand why a layer spec like the below:

```
"layer": [
    {"encoding": {
        "facet": {"field": "FEATURE_VALUE"},
        "x": {
            "field": "DATE",
            "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
            "field": "VALUE",
            "type": "quantitative"
        }
    },
    "mark": {
        "type": "line"
    }}
    ]
```

Throws an error to the effect of: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Meanwhile, the unit spec:

```
"encoding": {
        "facet": {"field": "FEATURE_VALUE"},
        "x": {
            "field": "DATE",
            "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
            "field": "VALUE",
            "type": "quantitative"
        }
    },
    "mark": {
        "type": "line"
    }
}
```

works just fine.

I can tell this has something to do with: [Altair: Can't facet layered plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872927/altair-cant-facet-layered-plots)

However, can't quite seem to answer the principle question: can I have a trellis plot using `facet` as well as have layers on top of that (for say tooltips, rulers, etc.)

Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I think there is a near-duplicate question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820357/why-column-facet-in-vega-lite-not-working-properly-with-layer - there are some thing I would like to figure out (ie. why `column` is not an allowable property in the operator but is in the encoding) before I answer my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vega-Lite provides two ways to specify facets: as an encoding (See [Facet, Row, and Column Encoding Channels](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html#facet-row-and-column-encoding-channels)) and as an operator (See [Facet Operator](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html#facet-operator)).

A layer chart is not allowed to contain a facet encoding, however a facet operator can contain a layer chart (the reason for this is that the semantics of layers containing incompatible facets is unclear).

So, instead of something like this:

```json
"layer": [
    {"encoding": {
        "facet": {"field": "FEATURE_VALUE"},
        "x": {
            "field": "DATE",
            "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
            "field": "VALUE",
            "type": "quantitative"
        }
    },
    "mark": {
        "type": "line"
    }}
]
```

you can do something like this:

```json
"facet": {"field": "FEATURE_VALUE"},
"spec": {
  "layer": [
    {"encoding": {
        "x": {
            "field": "DATE",
            "type": "temporal"
        },
        "y": {
            "field": "VALUE",
            "type": "quantitative"
        }
    },
    "mark": {
        "type": "line"
    }}
  ]
}
```